# VB.NET - Run shell without UAC?

Tags: vb.net, shell

We are using "hobocopy" to run backups of PST files.

The problem is that when hobocopy is ran, it pops up with a "User Access Control" dialog asking for permission to run.

I am using "Shell" in VB.net to run the hobocopy, but it needs to run in the background and quietly.

Is there a way to run the "Shell" command with admin privileges so it won't ask permission?

Comment: If you could, wouldn't that defeat the purpose for which UAC was put in place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that your application is launching hobocopy from code that you've written.

If you want to do this without any UAC prompt, then you have two options:

- disable UAC (not recommended!)
- launch your application with elevated permissions (i.e. "Run as administrator")

In a typical situation I'd not recommend either of these, but if you have to run hobocopy then (from the description of the app) I'd imagine there is no UAC-free option.

One other thing you could try is to right-click the application or shortcut in Windows, select "Properties," and enable the "Run as administrator" option in that dialogue. Depending on the exact permissions requested by the application, this *might* avoid UAC prompts. (For example: it works for Task Manager, but not for Regedit; I don't have Hobocopy to test.)

Comment: Just had a meeting about this. It looks like I will be making our own version of hobocopy instead. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Not that it's my business, but the reason hobocopy asks for UAC elevation is because that is *required* for the operation you're doing. Two possibilities exist: either you need the shadow copying that hobocopy provides, in which case any version you write will also require UAC elevation, or you don't - in which case your choice of tool is incorrect and you could easily do this with a different tool that doesn't require hobocopy. Either way, rolling your own is unlikely to be the best solution (unless it's just the `File.Copy` method).

Answer (score 0):

Why use Shell alltogether?

Try using

```
System.Diagnostics.Process
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
```

it gives you more possibilities, such as to not run it in the shell, or to execute a programm in a specific context (such as another user)

**Edit: As Dan point's out this does not solve the UAC problem, so here some more thoughts**

After searching the Net for solutions, i quickly noticed that there *are* ways to defeat UAC, but those are **Hacks**. So if you need to defeat UAC for a smooth HMI there is most likley a design error.

Ways to solve this problem may include:

- Executing hobocopy as Administrator (need to enable Administrator account)
- -> Eigther the way Dan described, or by using ProcessStartInfo.User
- Disabeling UAC
- Hacking your way into an elevated permission state
- Running the programm or an auxiliary process as a **service**, interfacing with it via ServiceControl

Only the latter of which seems to me as a legitimate solution, but would require to redesign your app.
Executing a piece of backup software on event or schedule seems to me like something a **service** should do anyways.

Comment: You'll still need UAC elevation if that's what the application requires, though.